# Run Thread in second plan Dotnet

Tags: .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am having an issue with dotnet core. I set a Task to runs on the thread pool with `Task.Run (async => await myFunction (). ConfigureAwait (false))`. But this specific pice of code finishes after the main thread, and it need to access to the database but is causing a null exception. Can i somehow access the database running this code in second thread?

Thanks!

Comment: You can access the database from any thread, but be aware some databases (like SQL CE) are not reentrant, so changing data from multiple threads can cause race conditions.  If you're getting a NullReferenceException you need to [debug your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/).

Comment: @DourHighArch thank you. My second thread is calling DbContext of EF but it can no support mult thread, so i need to manage the concurrence.

Comment: You can't use the same `DbContext` object on multiple threads, but you can create a new `DbContext` object on each thread.

Comment: @GabrielLuci yes, i guess i will use this one, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way i found to fix it, was creating a new DbContext for the background task to avoid conflicts!